# Can Scalejs and Kendo UI be integrated successfully?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, scalejs

I have just started looking into scalejs and how it can be integrated with Kendo UI. I already have a single page application that has been started in Kendo UI but I would like to utilise the modularisation capabilities/concepts of the scalejs architecture.

My questions are:

1. Should I use the scalejs routing or the Kenod UI routing?
2. Will Kendo UI and knockout will behave together or should I only use Kendo UI bindings?
3. How nicely will Kendo UI widgets function within the scalejs architecture, e.g., complex grid validations?

I assume that this can all be accomplished through abstracting Kendo within the core layer of scalejs?

Are there any examples for a starting point, Google is coming up empty for anything but a TODO sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the devs of scalejs here. We tried integration with kendo ui but found other libraries did what kendo did for free, and some even done better. We actually have some kendo examples, but there isn't a kendo extension as of yet. I am pretty sure you could easily use Kendos binding Library, but for consistency it would make more sense to use knockout because of the binding class provider (e.g. bindings) as it allows for separation of large bindings (e.g. configurations for advanced UI controls).

There's a website with some documentation and learning resources at http://www.scalejs.com. there's nothing there yet for making your own extensions but its not very hard. We have a lot of extensions you can use as references.